# Why can't I select a checkbox in my tableview?

Tags: checkbox, java-8, tableview, javafx-8

I have a javaFX 8 pane that contains a Piles TableView. When I select a Pile from the TableView, it queries a database and populates a second TableView with instances of LogExt. This second TableView includes a column of checkboxes mapped to the LogExt.selected boolean property.

When I run the application, I can't select any of the checkboxes.

LogExt:

```
public class LogExt {
    private BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private Log log;

    public LogExt(Log log) {
        this.setSelected(false);
        this.log = log;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected.set(selected);
    }

    public Log getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public void setLog(Log log) {
        this.log = log;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class CustomOrderController {
    @FXML
    private RadioButton openRadio;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup stageGroup;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Pile> pileTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pile, String> pileNoCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pile, String> speciesCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pile, String> gradeCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pile, String> logTypeCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pile, String> pileStartCol;
    @FXML
    private TableView<LogExt> logTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<LogExt, Boolean> selectedCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<LogExt, String> logSpeciesCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<LogExt, String> logGradeCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<LogExt, String> lengthCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<LogExt, String> diameterCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<LogExt, String> footageCol;
    @FXML
    private TextField totalFootageField;
    @FXML
    private TextField selectedFootageField;
    @FXML
    private Button clearButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField reportNoField;
    @FXML
    private Button saveButton;

    private ObservableList openPileList = null;
    private ObservableList finishedPileList = null;
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomOrderController.class);

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        super.initialize();

        // Set table columns to display proper values.
        pileNoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pileNo"));
        speciesCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            StringProperty stringProperty;
            if (param.getValue().getSpecies() != null)
                stringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getSpecies().getName());
            else stringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("All");
            return stringProperty;
        });
        gradeCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            StringProperty grade;
            if (param.getValue().getGrade() != null)
                grade = new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getGrade().getName());
            else grade = new SimpleStringProperty("All");
            return grade;
        });
        logTypeCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            StringProperty logType;
            if (param.getValue().getLogType() != null)
                logType = new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getLogType().getName());
            else logType = new SimpleStringProperty("All");
            return logType;
        });
        pileStartCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            StringProperty startDate;
            if (param.getValue().getPileStart() != null)
                startDate = new SimpleStringProperty(
                        param.getValue().getPileStart().format(DATETIMEFORMATTER));
            else startDate = null;
            return startDate;
        });
        // Add listener to catch table selections.
        pileTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> selectPile());

        // Add listener to catch radio button selections.
        stageGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((
                observable, oldValue, newValue) -> changeList());
        // Ensure values entered in the limit/warning fields are acceptable.
        reportNoField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(INTEGERSTRINGCONVERTER
                , 0, POSINTEGERFILTER));

        selectedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("selected"));
        selectedCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(selectedCol));
        logSpeciesCol.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getLog().getSpecies().getName()));
        logGradeCol.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getLog().getLogGrade().getName()));
        lengthCol.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(String.format("%d", param.getValue().getLog().getDeductionLength())));
        diameterCol.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(String.format("%d", param.getValue().getLog().getDeductionDiameter())));
        footageCol.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                new SimpleStringProperty(String.format("%d", param.getValue().getLog().getNetFootage())));
    }

    protected void refreshPane() {
        // Get the list of piles.
        openPileList = FXCollections.observableList(HibernateUtil.getProgramsCommonDB().
                query("from Pile where pileEnd = '" + NODATETIME.format(QUERYDATETIMEFORMATTER) + "'"));
        finishedPileList = FXCollections.observableList(HibernateUtil.getProgramsCommonDB().
                query("from Pile where pileEnd > '" + NODATETIME.format(QUERYDATETIMEFORMATTER) +
                        "' and consumeStart = '" + NODATETIME.format(QUERYDATETIMEFORMATTER) + "'"));
        changeList();

        // Set buttons and fields off to start.
        clear();
    }

    private void changeList() {
        clear();
        if (openRadio.isSelected()) pileTableView.setItems(openPileList);
        else pileTableView.setItems(finishedPileList);
    }

    private void enableWidgets(boolean yes) {
        clearButton.setDisable(!yes);
        logTable.setDisable(!yes);
        reportNoField.setDisable(!yes);
        LOG.info("OpenRadio: {}, enable: {}", openRadio.isSelected(), yes);
        saveButton.setDisable(true);
    }

    private void clearWidgets() {
        pileTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        logTable.getItems().clear();
        totalFootageField.clear();
        selectedFootageField.clear();
        reportNoField.clear();
    }

    @FXML
    private void clear() {
        clearWidgets();
        enableWidgets(false);
    }

    private void selectPile() {
        Pile currentPile = pileTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (currentPile != null) {
            // Fill the logs list with logs from this pile that have not been consumed.
            List oList = HibernateUtil.getLogsDB().query("from Log where pileID = "
                    + currentPile.getId()
                    + " and (consumeTime is null or consumeTime = '"
                    + NODATETIME.format(QUERYDATETIMEFORMATTER) + "')");
            List<LogExt> logList = new ArrayList<>();
            oList.forEach(o -> {
                LogExt logExt = new LogExt((Log) o);
                logList.add(logExt);
            });
            totalFootageField.setText(String.format("%d", logList.stream()
                    .mapToInt(value -> value.getLog().getNetFootage())
                    .sum()));
            logTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(logList));
            enableWidgets(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable editing on your table.

```
logTable.setEditable(true);
```

possibly on your column as well

```
selectedCol.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: I wish it were so simple. From the javadocs for JavaFX8, Checkboxtablecell: "Note that the CheckBoxTableCell renders the CheckBox 'live', meaning that the CheckBox is always interactive and can be directly toggled by the user. This means that it is not necessary that the cell enter its editing state (usually by the user double-clicking on the cell)."

Also, from the tablecolumn docs: "This, unlike TableView.editableProperty() and TreeTableView.editableProperty(), is true by default."

Experiment confirmed both these.

Comment: Live and learn. Once I made the table editable, it all worked. I don't understand why this has never been necessary in previous implementations of this functionality... but in this case, logTable.setEditable(true) worked.